# Collision-resistant single-pass EdDSA?

Tags: signature, collision-resistance, ed25519, eddsa

Is there any reason why collision resistant variants of ed25519 that use a single-pass aren't used instead? For example:

$n = h(noncekey \| m)$

$h(R \| pub \| n)$ instead of $h(R \| pub \| m)$

or alternatively if we want to not change the EdDSA algorithm itself and instead implement collision resistance on top of it:

Let $n'$ be a 256-bit number randomly generated by the signer:

$sig = n' \| S_{priv}(h(n' \| m))$

In both of these schemes (if I am not mistaken) an attacker that requests for a message $m$ to be signed by the signer (such as in the case of certificate signing) should not be able to trick the signer into generating a signature that can be used with a message $m'$ where $m \neq m'$ if $h$ is not collision resistant.